# Check iOS restrictions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking for a way to detect which restrictions are enabled on the device. For example, I have safari disabled through restrictions but I don't know how to determine that.

I know I can use a hack that check if the app has been sent to the background but ideally would like to be able to just check all the restrictions.

Thanks

Comment: what restrictions are you talking about? accessing photos, contacts, push notifications?

Comment: Does `UIApplication canOpenURL:` work to see if Safari is disabled or not?

Comment: @luk2302 I would like to know about all the ones that can be enabled via this menu http://www.softwarewithstyle.com/uploads/g013/2.set_the_parental_restrictions_on_iphone.jpg

My immediate concern is whether or no safari has been disabled.

Comment: @rmaddy no. it's always returns true for a valid url.